# .NET / C# - Convert char[] to string

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, char

What is the proper way to turn a `char[]` into a string?

The `ToString()` method from an array of characters doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 854, accepted):

There's [a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char())) for this:

```
char[] chars = {'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'};
string s = new string(chars);
```

Comment: Note that `new string(null)` yields `String.Empty` and **not** `null`! 
If you want to keep `null`, you can make an extension method `static string ToStringSafe(this char[] buf) { return buf == null ? null : new string(buf); }`.

Comment: @Skod: Seeing that it's impossible for a "new" expression to return a value other than an object instance, that should not come as a surprise to anyone.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Throwing an exception is also a reasonable thing to do. That's the behavior I would have guessed for passing null to the string constructor.

Comment: Valid for `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` ?

Answer (score 111):

Use the constructor of string which accepts a char[]

```
char[] c = ...;
string s = new string(c);
```

Comment: If only you were three minutes faster, you would have answered before the question was asked!

Comment: Forget minutes. It's just 17 seconds. My answer just above is my 2nd high-est voted answer on the site. In fact I'm here now because someone just voted it again, almost 10 years later. And the two answers aren't really any different... but mine was posted 17 seconds faster, and that's meant a 500 vote difference :/

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - 14 years later, and another vote! Cheers.

Answer (score 43):

```
char[] characters;
...
string s = new string(characters);
```

Answer (score 34):

One other way:

```
char[] chars = {'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'};
string s = string.Join("", chars);
//we get "a string"
// or for fun:
string s = string.Join("_", chars);
//we get "a_ _s_t_r_i_n_g"
```

Comment: `string.Join` only accepts `string[]` instead of `char[]`

Comment: @sky91 not only, you can use String.Join<T> Method and any T[] as parameter, T.ToString() will be called

Comment: then you should write `string.Join<char>("_", chars)` instead of `string.Join("_", chars)`

Comment: Compiler does it automatically as chars type is known on compile time.

Answer (score 27):

Another alternative

```
char[] c = { 'R', 'o', 'c', 'k', '-', '&', '-', 'R', 'o', 'l', 'l' };
string s = String.Concat( c );

Debug.Assert( s.Equals( "Rock-&-Roll" ) );
```

Comment: `String.Concat` is nice because it accepts `IEnumerable<char>` as a parameter, so we don't have to call `ToArray()` when using LINQ.

Answer (score 23):

```
String mystring = new String(mychararray);
```

Answer (score 22):

Use the string constructor which takes as arguments a Char array, the start position in the array, and the length of array. Syntax is given below:

```
string stringFromArray = new string(charArray, 0, charArray.Length);
```

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for. But I didn't know of any class named CharArray. Did you perhaps mean something like:
`char[] charArray = new char[5] { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0', '\0' };
  string charsAsString = new string(charArray, 0, 3); // only want part of array.`

Comment: CharArray is not class, just variable of type char[]

Answer (score 0):

[String.Join(string separator, char[] charArray)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0) concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a collection, using the specified separator between each element or member:

```
char[] c = { 'A', ' ', 'B', ' ', 'C', '&', 'D'};
string stringResult =  string.Join("", c);  //A B C&D
```