# char[] to string in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET / C# - Convert char[] to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324009/net-c-sharp-convert-char-to-string)

When I try to call .ToString() on my char[] I expect a string to be created of the values in the char[]. Instead I get "char[]" as a string, the type, which is not what I want. What am I missing here?

In Java .toString() on a char[] prints the values from a char[] as a string.

Thanks

Comment: Any code to show us what you're doing?

Comment: What is the complexity of string(arr) ? What is it doing behind the scenes?

Comment: Why would you downvote me? How am I supposed to know there was a duplicate? It didn't show up when I was posting. Excuse me for breathing.

Comment: @Dave: *"How am I supposed to know there was a duplicate?"* - You search before posting an answer... or, you know, consult the documentation.  You have to assume that such a trivial question has been asked before, this is just lazy.

Comment: @EdS. I did search and this is what showed up. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=char%5B%5D+to+string+in+c%23 - Notice that besides my post there are hundreds of results. None of the correct answers are on the first 5 pages. Do you want me to waste more time? That's not lazy, that's efficient.

Comment: And when you add the word "convert"... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+char%5B%5D+to+string+in+c%23&submit=search

Comment: Also, checking the documentation for `String` would have been a good first stab.

Comment: The word convert wasn't in my mind. I'm sorry I don't have the .NET API memorized. I hope you feel good about yourself.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert I don't appreciate your sarcasm. I understand marking a question as closed because it is a duplicate, but down-voting is a totally different thing. That is punishing ignorance. You had to make the mental assumption that I am lazy and didn't try to search for an answer which was completely false. I did try to search. Just because I couldn't think of the word "convert" and come to the right duplicate answer does not warrant a downvote. I'm sorry. And I know the SO founders would agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good old `String` constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx

```
new String(chars)
```

Comment: +1. to all calls to constructor. Sort of sad to see question "how to create string from XXX" that is directly listed on MSDN...

Answer (score 5):

```
char[] charArray = new char[10];
.... 
string myString = new string(charArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

As simple as:

```
string s = new string(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple actually:

```
char[] myCharArray = new char[5];

myCharArray[0] = 'H';
myCharArray[1] = 'e';
myCharArray[2] = 'l';
myCharArray[3] = 'l';
myCharArray[4] = 'o';

string myString = new String(myCharArray);
Console.WriteLine("This is my String: " + myString;
```

Right? :-)