# returning array of characters from function

Tags: c#, arrays

how do i return an array of characters from function? I'm currently using c#.I have this function :

```
public char bsortfunction(char[] letters)
{
  char temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
  {
   for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
   {
    if (letters[i] < letters[x])
    {
      temp = letters[i];
      letters[i] = letters[x];
      letters[x] = temp;
     }

   }

  }
   return (cant seem to figure out how to return the letters[])
```

}

```
private void btnsort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   char[] characters = txtstring.Text.ToCharArray();       
   lblresult.Text = bsortfunction(characters);

}
```

Comment: so it should be a public char. okay i'll try it sir, thanks

Comment: please clarify your question.do you want to return a string or char array?

Comment: i want to return a char array

Comment: Do it! char-array is noted with [] after char: `char[]`

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to convert your character array into a string, you can write:

```
return new string(letters);
```

If you need to return an actual character array, you need to change the function's return type to `char[]` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to return a string. Try this :

```
public char[] lettersbsortfunction(char[] letters)
{
  char temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
  {
   for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
   {
    if (letters[i] < letters[x])
    {
      temp = letters[i];
      letters[i] = letters[x];
      letters[x] = temp;
     }

   }

  }
   return letters;

}
```

Comment: thanks sir. now the problem is when i call the function. it says that it cannot convert char[] to string

Comment: So return a string =) look at dvnrrs answer

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
return new string(letters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return a new string:

```
return new string(letters);
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
  public char[] bsortfunction(char[] letters)
    {
        char temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
            {
                if (letters[i] < letters[x])
                {
                    temp = letters[i];
                    letters[i] = letters[x];
                    letters[x] = temp;
                }

            }

        }
        return (letters);
    }
```

Or you can use:

```
return new string(letters);
```

[sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324009/net-c-sharp-convert-char-to-string):

```
char[] chars = {'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'};
string s = new string(chars);
```

Comment: i got an error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'char'

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'string'. it refers to this code now: lblresult.Text = bsortfuncion(characters);

Comment: Use:return new string(letters);

Comment: there's no errors in the method anymore. the error now is when i call the function: lblresult.text = bsortfunction(characters);. it says that it cannot convert char[] to string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return string try:

```
 return new String(letters);
```

If you want to return char array change return type of your method to char array:

```
public char[] lettersbsortfunction(char[] letters)
```

And :

```
return letters;
```

Alternatively you can use [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword in this case.If you want to just manipulate letters array,you don't need to return anything:

```
 public void bsortfunction(ref char[] letters)
 {
    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
    {
      for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
      {
        if (letters[i] < letters[x])
        {
           temp = letters[i];
          letters[i] = letters[x];
          letters[x] = temp;
       }

   }

 }
```