# can't convert simple list to string in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code works fine on wpf.

In my code list1 will work but if convert a string to a list of char and change again to string it showing error of : can't convert from char[] to string [].
need suggestion.

here's the code :

```
        string x = "hello";

        List<char> list = x.ToList<char>();

        //error
        string combindedString = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());

        string xz = string.Join("", list);
        //---

        //okay....
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>()
                                {
                                    "Red",
                                    "Blue",
                                    "Green"
                                };

        string output = string.Join("", list1.ToArray());
```

[image]

in wpf:

[image]

Comment: `string.Join`can take a `string[]` not a `char[]`

Comment: You can not do string.join on character array.

Comment: @JSteward it works on wpf. not in unity?

Comment: how can I convert in that first part of the code, list to a string?

Comment: Ahhh you're using the old version of Unity. That version used .Net 3.5 when a `char[]` didn't implement `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET / C# - Convert char\[\] to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324009/net-c-sharp-convert-char-to-string)

Comment: `list.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray()`

Comment: @bulliedMonster see my previous comment, targeting the older .Net framework is the source of your problem. Either target a higher, v4.6.1?, maybe still in experimental stage in unity, or rewrite the code to not use arrays of chars

Comment: @JSteward Thanks a lot for information. I didn't know that.

Comment: @JSteward Arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>` since .NET 2.0. The problem is most likely a missing `using System.Linq;`

Comment: nop. That reference is already added.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ah couldn't remember that exactly and jumped to a conclusion. But removing `using System.Linq` doesn't change anything beside `ToList`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the question is about converting list to a string not char[] in duplication link.

Comment: You are anyway doing `list.ToArray()`. The answer below you accepted also does the same thing. It is in fact the same code which is mentioned in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I suspect the source of your issue still lies with using the older .Net Framework that is default with Unity, 3.5 I believe. You have some options, to work around the problem though:

- You can target an update framework, I believe Unity supports up to 4.6.1 in experimental mode.
- You can work around converting a `char[]` to string.
- Or just use the string constructor:

A simple example:

```
[Test]
public void StringTest()
{
    string x = "hello";
    List<char> list = x.ToList<char>();
    string newStr = new string(list.ToArray());
    Assert.IsTrue(newStr == x);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I changed .Net version to work with and my code works now.

Comment: And I don't know why people downvoting stuff to a original problem.

Answer (score -1):

This can easily be achieved with a loop. 
            string x = "hello"

```
        List<char> list = x.ToList<char>();

        string originalword = "";

        foreach (var letter in list)
        {
            originalword += letter.ToString();
        }

        // original word is equal to hello
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a nice answer. However its okay but I'm concerned about performance.

Comment: Another way you might try is to convert the list<char> into an array<char> and then create a string like so: string original = new string(array<char>); Not sure how well that would do on performance though :) You didn't mention that in your post