# Print first letter of every word in MVC helper method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this helper method on an MVC View that returns the first name and last name of the user (Windows autheticated application)

```
@helper AccountName()
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        @principal.GivenName<text> </text>@principal.Surname
    }
}
```

How can I extract the initials of the user(first letter of first name and first letter of last name)?

I tried with linq:

```
@AccountName().ToString().Split(' ').Select(x => x[0]).ToArray()
```

But that results:

```
System.Char[]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That character array contains the first letter of first and last name.. you already have your own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output the first letters as a string instead of a character array (in order to make the `ToString` work), use the string constructor. This is already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324009/net-c-sharp-convert-char-to-string).

However, to make that work, you do need to wrap this in a code block (`@(...)`). Then it wil print correctly.

```
@(new string(@AccountName().ToString().Split(' ').Select(x => x[0]).ToArray()))
```

Comment: I need to get this code to work on the MVC View...

Comment: So, why doesn't it work?

Comment: _Type expected_ compilation error.

Comment: And if you just wrap that in a block `@(...)`?

Comment: You're right... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a neat Regex;

```
// This could be compiled and cached.
var initialsRegex = new Regex(@"(\b[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*\.* ?"); 

// This gives the initials
var initials = initialsRegex.Replace(AccountName, "$1");
```

This will also include names that contain initials with `.` i.e. John S. Doe

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
foreach (string s in @AccountName.Split(" ".ToCharArray()))
    shortName += s.Substring(0,1).ToUpper();
```