# Convert List of char array into string list

Tags: c#

How can I convert List of char array:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
a f z w m y r z
z z z z z z z z
```

to List of string:

```
1az
2fz
3zz
4wz
5mz
6yz
7rz
8zz
```

Comment: What did you try so far? So we can help you.

Comment: How is your first array represented in C#? Or what form is it given? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can take a look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324013/2845389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int length = charArrays.Min(arr => arr.Length);
List<string> stringList = Enumerable.Range(0, length)
    .Select(i => String.Concat(charArrays.Select(arr => arr[i])))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this `linq` still looks like him :p

Comment: You have not supplied a variable name for the result... ;)

Comment: I checked it. Worked fine after giving the result a name. :)