# cannot convert from 'char[]' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I was trying to make a save dialog from a rich text document but I keep getting an error on the text.

> Error:
>
> ArgumentNullException
>
> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'char[]' to 'string[]'

I'm new to c# so I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(ofd.FileName.ToString(), richTextBox1.Text.ToArray());
```

Comment: You probably want to use File.WriteAllText(ofd.FileName.ToString(), richTextBox1.Text) since it appears that it is already a string. WriteAllLines expect a string array, and by doing .ToArray() on a string you are creating an array of characters instead

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(ofd.FileName, richTextBox1.Lines);` (if you want to use the `Lines` Property, which is an array of strings)

Comment: As @.dbso and @.Jimi wrote, ToArray is not needed and Lines should be used instead. Just for information: [.NET / C# - Convert char\[\] to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324009/net-c-sharp-convert-char-to-string)

Comment: If what you quoted is verbatim, I wonder why it's an argumentnullexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different method:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ofd.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);
```

I'd recommend avoiding to use Lines for this; it's a waste of resources to split the text into N strings only to write them all back to a combined file

Why didn't your first attempt work? `WriteAllLines` requires an array of strings. If you call `.ToArray()` on a string you get an array of characters; strings and characters are very different things.

`ToArray()` is a LINQ method that works because a string can be treated as an enumerable sequence of char. Typically it's very rare that you would do so and you would probably use the dedicated `string.ToCharArray()` method if you did want a char array from a string. Mostly I use it when splitting strings on multiple characters: `someString.Split(".,?!'-/:;()".ToCharArray());` as it's more readable than putting each char separately

You're more likely to use `ToArray()` later on for things like filtering one array using LINQ and turning the result into an array again:

```
Person[] smiths = people.Where(person => person.LastName == "Smith").ToArray();
```

---

Other points:

OpenFileDialog's FileName is already a string; you don't need to `ToString()` it

Please get into the habit of renaming your controls after you add them to a form (top of the properties grid, the (Name) line, takes two seconds). It's a lot easier for us on the internet (and you in 3 weeks' time) to be able to read `usernameTextBox` and go "*oh, that's the username textbox*" than it is to be wondering "*is it textbox56 or textbox27 that is the username? I'll just go into the form designer and check..*"