# c# storing reversed string into another string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reverse

block1 works:-

```
String input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
char[] output = input.Reverse().ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

when I try to store the output **into a new String**, block2 works as well:-

```
String input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
char[] output = input.Reverse().ToArray()
String output2 = new String(output);
Console.WriteLine(output2);
```

But when I try to store the output **into a String**, block3 does not works:-

```
String input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
char[] output = input.Reverse().ToArray()
String output2 = output; //I tried to use convert.ToString() as well,  but it didn't work
Console.WriteLine(output2);
```

why does block 2 works and block 3 does not ??

Comment: output is a `char[]` and output2 is `string`.  You need to convert char[] to string. For block2, you use the string constructor to do this.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324009/net-c-sharp-convert-char-to-string

Comment: In c# we cannot directly assign a string from a char[], a string uses an internal char[] and is immutable. You have to use the `new String(charBuffer);` Syntax. The only way you could write directly to the string would be to use unsafe code, which is not recommended.

Comment: Block 3 will have resulted in an error message from the compiler. What was it about the message that was unclear? I'm interested to know so we can use an insights gained from it about how you perceive C# behaves, to better answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does block 2 works and block 3 does not ??

block 2 uses the [constructor of string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char___) that accepts a char array. This is an existing constructor that Microsoft have provided that forms a new string

block 3 would require there to be an implicit conversion defined between a char array and a string, because the output from `Reverse().ToArray()` is an array of char, not a string. It is important to appreciate that strings can be treated as `IEnumerable<char>`, and you can run LINQ methods like `Reverse` on them, but because they're treated as sequences of char on the way in, they come out as sequences of char, not strings. You cannot directly assign a char array to a string variable because Microsoft have provided no such conversion

You might find [this discussion on SESE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324171/why-doesnt-system-string-include-a-constructor-taking-an-ienumerablechar) interesting and relevant

Footnote; you asked why you cannot call `ToString` on a char array- again, there just isn't an overload of `ToString` on a `char[]` that turns the char array into a string, because Microsoft haven't provided one.

There are plenty enough ways of making a `char[]` into a `string` (your block 2 is ideal) that Microsoft don't need to spend the time and effort to make another, and you have to also consider there might be code out there that *relies* on `someCharArray.ToString()` returning `System.Char[]` - not everyone knows you can do `myObject is char[]`, they might have done `myObject.ToString == "System.Char[]"` to check if the object is a char array.

Whenever a language is upgraded with new features, every possible problem that the new feature could cause, will be investigated. The risk of adding `.ToString()` to `char[]` that produces a string from the characters, and having it silently (because it won't cause a compile error) break potentially millions of codebases around the world is just too great, when there isn't any benefit over what you can do already:

```
var chars = new[]{'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d'}

var s = chars.ToString();     //produces "System.Char[]"
var s = new string(chars);    //produces "Hello World"
                         ^
                  one extra keystroke
```

It only costs one more keystroke to use the constructor version, and if you use modern c# that doesn't require stating the type after the new, so long as the type is on the other side, it's shorter even than the older `var` version too :)

```
var s = chars.ToString();
string s = new(chars);
```